# OpenCV for Unity3D: Xcode signing error for opencv2 lib

Tags: xcode, opencv, unity-game-engine, signing

I would need help to solve the error, Xcode is firing, when building the application, which includes the OpenCV library for Unity.

*Error loading /var/containers/Bundle/Application/AAD49F35-2BE7-432D-85D1-81B2489C23F5/ubs.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework:  dlopen(/var/containers/Bundle/Application/AAD49F35-2BE7-432D-85D1-81B2489C23F5/my.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework, 265): Library not loaded: @rpath/opencv2.framework/opencv2
Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/AAD49F35-2BE7-432D-85D1-81B2489C23F5/my.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework
Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/AAD49F35-2BE7-432D-85D1-81B2489C23F5/my.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/Frameworks/opencv2.framework/opencv2: code signature in (/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/AAD49F35-2BE7-432D-85D1-81B2489C23F5/my.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/Frameworks/opencv2.framework/opencv2) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.*

I tried to enable "disable library validation" in the signing settings for each target. Also under the UnityFramework build target I set the opencv.framework to "embed without signing".

Not sure what Apple needs to make this run. It seems they changed something again (I build the application months ago without problems).

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

For all those guys who had the same problem:

In my case I could fix it in xcode with:

- In the section "Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content" you´ll have to include the opencv2.framework by your own. It wount appear, if you search it on the "+" list, so you will have to click the "+" and add it manualy with the Add Other dropdown menu on the bottom. Search for the opencv2.framework folder in the build folder under frameworks -> OpenCVForUnity -> Plugins -> IOS -> opencv2.framework. Select this folder, add it and chose "Embed & Sign" in XCode.
- In the build settings disable "Enable Bitcode" for each Targets.
- Of course check for the camera (Yes), microphone (depend on your app) and localization (depend on your app) permissions in the p.list file.

Hope this helps if you had the same problem.

Best,

Thomas

Comment: This worked for me after trying a lot of solutions, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

An issue for Catalin and Big Sur is that he .a file is automatically removed unless you go to Mac System Preferences and allow it in Security + Privacy